# Recommendations on a SFTP Server

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I plan on sending and receiving files via sftp, what is the recommended software server program to use when doing batch jobs of sending and receiving files? This will be done on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is there any other SFTP server than the one provided by OpenSSH at all?

Comment: joschi, Wikipedia has a list out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SFTP_server_software ; Also http://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/index.html - I haven't used it but I am a big fan of SecureCRT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [**OpenSSH**](http://www.openssh.com/) which is probably already installed on your machine for [sftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol).

Answer (score 1):

**OpenSSH**

Your Ubuntu machine probably already has OpenSSH installed so I'd recommend using that.

As for a client program and ease of use... I personally like Tunnelier by Bitvise.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo the two other recommendations for OpenSSH, and mention that it also comes with a perfectly serviceable SFTP client, which is just the thing for invoking in batch scripts.